# Tengo que retornar las propiedades únicas de cada objeto recibido (no sé si el código está bien escrito)

Tags: javascript, objeto, callback

Utilicé como ejemplo 2 objetos obja y objb y al conocer sus propiedades puedo hacer el return, lo que quisiera saber es si la función recibe 2 o más objetos con diferentes propiedades ¿cómo escribo el código para retornar aquellas propiedades que son únicas de cada objeto? Gracias de antemano.

```
 function clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) {
        // La funcion recibe dos objetos "obj1" y "obj2".
        // Retornar las keys de las propiedades que sean únicas en cada objeto.
        // Ej:
        // let obj1 = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"}
        // let obj2 = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"}
        // clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) retorna => ["apellido", "segundoNombre"];
        //
        // Tu código`:
      
         let obja = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"};
      
         let objb = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"};
      
      var unica = clavesUnicas.filter(function(elemento){
        
        return obja.apellido && objb.segundoNombre;
        
      })
      
      return unica;
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar `set()` para obtener las claves únicas:

```js
let obja = {
  nombre: "Luciano",
  apellido: "Nicolau"
};

let objb = {
  nombre: "Lio",
  segundoNombre: "Gustavo"
};


let unicos = Array.from(new Set(Object.keys({ ...obja,
  ...objb
})))

console.log(unicos)
```

En pasos esto se veria asi:

```js
let obja = {
  nombre: "Luciano",
  apellido: "Nicolau"
};

let objb = {
  nombre: "Lio",
  segundoNombre: "Gustavo"
};

//Creamos un solo objeto con las llaves. 
let nuevoObjeto = { ...obja,
  ...objb
}

//Obtenemos solo los las claves

let claves = Object.keys(nuevoObjeto)
let sinDuplicados = new Set(claves)
//Esto es por que el set tienen operaciones diferentes que 
//array. 
let nuevoArreglo = Array.from(sinDuplicados)


console.log(nuevoArreglo)
```

Comment: Ah perfecto, soy algo nuevo en programación y no conocía el método set(), ahora me fijo bien como se usa. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En los objetos literales, las claves siempre son únicas, ejemplo:

```js
const obj = {"a":1, "a":2}

console.log(obj)
```

Con solo concatenarlos, quedan las claves únicas:

```js
const obja = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"};
      
const objb = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"};

const res = Object.keys({...obja, ...objb});

console.log(res);
```

Si quisieras encontrar las claves que no se repiten entre objetos, puedes filtrarlas:

```js
const obja = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"};
      
const objb = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"};

const estan_en_a_y_no_en_b = Object.keys(obja).filter(k=>!Object.keys(objb).includes(k));

const estan_en_b_y_no_en_a = Object.keys(objb).filter(k=>!Object.keys(obja).includes(k));

console.log([...estan_en_a_y_no_en_b, ...estan_en_b_y_no_en_a]);
```